# CEF4Delphi - My program doesn't get visible again using Alt-Tab when browser is active

Tags: windows, delphi, focus, chromium, chromium-embedded

I have a Windows program, let's call it 'MyApp', written in Delphi, with embedded chromium on a certain tab. I use [CEF4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi) and I have a problem.

When I use 'MyApp' and the embedded browser is active, I can activate another program (using Alt-Tab or click the icon in the task bar). That's no problem. **But when I want to activate 'MyApp' again, it won't get visible or brought to the front**. I can not see 'MyApp'. The other program remains visible, however the icon in the taskbar is highlighted. To use 'MyApp', I will have to minimize the other program, so I will see it again.

This problem only occurs when the embedded browser in 'MyApp' is activated.

The chromium is running as a different process and created like recommended in the documentation: https://www.briskbard.com/index.php?lang=en&pageid=cef#usage

The dpr looks like this:

```
program MyApp;

{$R *.dres}

// uses files

{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED or IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP or IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP}
{$SetPEOptFlags IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE}
{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE}

begin
  NullStrictConvert := System.false;

  GlobalCEFApp := TCefApplication.Create;
  if GlobalCEFApp.StartMainProcess then
  begin
    PauseMadExcept;

    Application.Initialize;
    // ... create forms ...
    Application.Run;
```

Comment: I tested some CEF4Delphi demos and pressed alt-tab several times with other applications running at the same time and I couldn't reproduce this issue. 

The Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True; line is missing. Have you tried adding it?

Please, provide a complete minimal example to test this issue.

Comment: I have this problem in a large program, it's not occuring in demo's. I can not share that program, for it's customers code. The Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True; line is missing in my dpr, yes. I will check if that causes this problem when I have time, thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: I have the same problem with Magix Video Edit Pro (under Windows 10). Maybe it's related? https://www.magix.info/us/forum/when-using-alt-tab-video-edit-pro-does-not-get-focussed-windows-10--1251611/ - Also discussed over here (wihtout solution): https://github.com/jimradford/superputty/issues/267 - Could you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a Windows 10 bug!

Try this (which helped me with another software, Magix Video Edit Pro):

Disable the "Snap windows" under System > Settings > Multitasking and now the <kbd>ALT + TAB</kbd> works again. The software gets focused.

[image: snap windows system settings win10]

Update: The bug reappeared but still, it worked some time after disabling "Snap windwos". Anyone with some more hints, please comment below.